# What is the theory behind the odeintw package for complex matrix differential equations?

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

In most of the below answers for complex matrix differential equations, the odeintw package has been suggested.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45970853/7952027

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320130/7952027

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747232/7952027

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26582411/7952027

I want to know the theory behind the manipulations done in the code of [odeintw](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw).
Like why one has to build that banded jacobian, the idea behind the functions _complex_to_real_jac, _transform_banded_jac, etc.

Comment: A complex matrix space is a real vector space, so a complex matrix can be represented by an array of real numbers preserving this linear structure. All odeintw has to do is to wrap odeint or better the function given to it with this basis transformation, forward and backwards.

Comment: I think the issue is non-trivial.

Comment: Yes, it is that trivial. Now if you want to speed up the computation by providing the Jacobian, it also needs to be translated into the real form. In the method of lines as example you get banded Jacobians, the translation has to keep that property for efficiency reasons.

Comment: The nontrivial part arises when you want to specify the Jacobian via the `Dfun` argument.  The complex Jacobian requires that the right-hand side of the equation be complex differentiable (i.e. [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function)).  For example, the function f(z) = z* (the complex conjugate) is not complex differentiable, so you can't specify a complex Jacobian for the equation dz/dt = z*.  You would have to rewrite it as a system of real equations.  (This example is in the docstring of `odeintw`.)

Comment: If the right-hand side is complex differentiable, then you can give a complex Jacobian via `Dfun`.

Comment: Where can I read more about this "method of lines"  @LutzLehmann

Comment: Where can I read more about whatever you spoke @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: M-o-L is a common method in solving PDE of the heat or wave equation type. Essentially, it discretizes the space dimension(s) while leaving the time dimension continuous, resulting in a large-dimensional ODE system in time direction. The resulting Jacobians only are non-zero at nearest-neighbor interactions, thus very sparse, and have a banded structure if the discretization is via a regular grid.

Comment: Can https://stackoverflow.com/a/65838993/7952027 be used instead of odeintw ?@LutzLehmann

Comment: Can https://stackoverflow.com/a/65838993/7952027 be used instead of odeintw?  @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: yes it seems so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments.

> A complex matrix space is a real vector space, so a complex matrix can be represented by an array of real numbers preserving this linear structure. All odeintw has to do is to wrap odeint or better the function given to it with this basis transformation, forward and backward.

> Now if you want to speed up the computation by providing the Jacobian, it also needs to be translated into the real form. In the method of lines as example you get banded Jacobians, the translation has to keep that property for efficiency reasons.

> M-o-L is a common method in solving PDE of the heat or wave equation type. Essentially, it discretizes the space dimension(s) while leaving the time dimension continuous, resulting in a large-dimensional ODE system in time direction. The resulting Jacobians only are non-zero at nearest-neighbor interactions, thus very sparse, and have a banded structure if the discretization is via a regular grid.

- [lutz-lehmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088138/lutz-lehmann)

> The nontrivial part arises when you want to specify the Jacobian via the Dfun argument. The complex Jacobian requires that the right-hand side of the equation be complex differentiable (i.e. holomorphic). For example, the function f(z) = z* (the complex conjugate) is not complex differentiable, so you can't specify a complex Jacobian for the equation dz/dt = z*. You would have to rewrite it as a system of real equations. (This example is in the docstring of odeintw.)

> If the right-hand side is complex differentiable, then you can give a complex Jacobian via Dfun.

- [warren-weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser)